# Require JS error mime(text/html) not supported

Tags: magento2, error, requirejs, console

I have just installed **magento** with **composer** and I am facing require js errors in my javascript **console** and the **page** in **blank**. no features are exposed

Comment: try to deploy your static content

Comment: I have deployed the static content i have the same problem

Comment: please share a screenshot